# Can computers aid in solving problems of Topology/Differential Geometry

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, soft-question, math-software

I was wondering whether computers can, or have been of any aid in fields such as topology and differential geometry. Usually when I think of computers, only problems of "finite"/"discrete" nature come to mind. But can they be used to tackle the "continuous" problems of mathematics?

Comment: computational topology? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_topology

Comment: These computational methods depend on a given triangulation of the space in question which is again a discrete problem.

Comment: One could argue that a big part of the research effort in say algebraic topology is devoted to the task of transforming geometric statements into combinatorics or linear algebra, because the latter are usually easier to approach and in particular easier for computers to handle. The entire machinery of cohomology is based on that heuristic, and homotopy theory as well.

Comment: Computers can at best approximate non-discrete problems. But they can't solve them.

Comment: Depends on the problem. You can get close bounds if you're very careful with how floating point computation errors are propagated. For instance Benson-Laugesen-Siudeja used a computer to answer an interesting PDE question in this paper: http://www.irishmathsoc.org/bull78/Articles/Siudeja/Siudeja.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Interesting classes of minimal surfaces were discovered by computer, and then Meeks and Hoffman knew to look for proofs of deep theorems. See, for example, [this paper in the Bulletin of the AMS](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183554179) and [this expository article](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4613-9711-3_5) and [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF03023947).